# Need help in configuring the ejabberd

Tags: java, ejabberd

I am new to ejabberd server and i am using ejabberd-15.04. Now for that I downloaded the code(erlang setup was done already) and i followed all the steps to build it.

1). ./configure
2). make
3). sudo make install

and now after going to "/etc/ejabberd/" i could start it or stop it using ejabberctl start/stopm command. But in this folder i could not see any configure.cfg to configure my ejabberd for my application.

But when i install the binary that time i could see the configure.cfg file there;which i modified and tested.But as i may have to apply a patch on ejabberd i need to build it through source and then use it.

Can anyone guide me how shall i do in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into ejabberd.yml which is the new Yaml config file format.

Comment: Thanks for it.Could you please also guide me how can i create multiple instances of ejabberd on a single debian machine...the idea is to check the clustering in ejabberd and all things around it...so that when the actual things comes we have an idea.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but it does not look ejabberd specific. You can always install several instances of a service, configuring it to listen on different TCP/IP ports.